# How do i print the date and time of specific lines that contain a certain key word using Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In other words i need Ruby to read from the attached log file and report the dates and time that has the keyword MAY_DAY. I am able to print out all the information but I don't have the slightest idea on how to print out the specific entries.

I am an uber noob and find ruby extremely difficult to understand. I appreciate all help and respectful criticism. Thanks

test.txt

```
Oct 15 12:54:01 WHERE IS THE LOVIN MAY_DAY
Oct 16 23:15:44 WHAT THE HECK CAN I DO ABOUT IT HUMP_DAY 
Oct 16 14:16:09 I LOVE MY BABY GIRL MAY_DAY 
Oct 16 08:25:18 CAN WAIT UNTIL MY BABY RECOVERS CRYSTAL_WIFE 
Oct 18 17:48:38 I HOPE HE STOP MESSING WITH THESE FOOLISH CHILDREN TONY_SMITH 
Oct 19 05:17:58 GAME TIME GO HEAD AND GET ME MAY_DAY 
Oct 20 10:23:33 GAMESTOP IS WHERE ITS AT GAME_DAY
Oct 21 03:54:27 WHAT IS GOING ON WITH MY LUNCH HUNGRY_MAN
```

RestartMonitor.rb

```
class RestartMonitor    

   counter = 1
   begin
      file = File.new("test.txt", "r")
      while (line = file.gets)
         puts "#{counter}: #{line}"
         counter = counter + 1
      end

 end
```

When i run the file i get the following results:

```
Oct 15 12:54:01 WHERE IS THE LOVIN MAY_DAY
Oct 16 23:15:44 WHAT THE HECK CAN I DO ABOUT IT HUMP_DAY 
Oct 16 14:16:09 I LOVE MY BABY GIRL MAY_DAY 
Oct 16 08:25:18 CAN WAIT UNTIL MY BABY RECOVERS CRYSTAL_WIFE 
Oct 18 17:48:38 I HOPE HE STOP MESSING WITH THESE FOOLISH CHILDREN TONY_SMITH 
Oct 19 05:17:58 GAME TIME GO HEAD AND GET ME MAY_DAY 
Oct 20 10:23:33 GAMESTOP IS WHERE ITS AT GAME_DAY
Oct 21 03:54:27 WHAT IS GOING ON WITH MY LUNCH HUNGRY_MAN
```

When i run the code i would like it to only display the date and times that have the keyworld MAY_DAY. so the output should be:

```
Oct 15 12:54:01
Oct 16 14:16:09
Oct 19 05:17:58
```

Comment: please give an example of what you want to do.

Comment: Is this a better explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be like so (within a block that's iterating over the lines in the file, obviously):

```
if line.include?('MAY_DAY')
  puts line[0..14]
end
```

Since the date information (which is what you want output) appears in the same position and is the same length in every line, we don't bother doing any parsing of the text for the output - just spit out the first 15 characters.

I'm tempted to try to compress all of this into a single regular expression, but this ought to work. Obviously, you could do something other than print out the date within the conditional, and if you wanted to work with it *as* a date, you could pass it to `DateTime.parse()` (just remember to `require 'date'` first).

Comment: or just: puts line [0,15] if line['MAY_DAY']